# What is wrong with this Verilog code?

Tags: verilog, seven-segment-display

I wrote a module that works as a counter (seconds) and displays the number on two seven segment displays on an Altera board, one for each digit.

Here is the module:

```
module assignment2_sevenseg(clkin, seg1_output, seg2_output);

input clkin;
output reg [6:0] seg1_output;
output reg [6:0] seg2_output;
reg currentTime;

assignment2_sec seconds(.clkin(clkin), .output_sec(currentTime));

always @(currentTime)   

begin


digitaltimer timer(currentTime/10, seg1_output);  //left segment (line 14)
digitaltimer timer1(currentTime%10, seg2_output); //right segment (line 15)

end

endmodule
```

The assignment2_sec module is another module used to count/increment the seconds. It should be working fine. The errors im getting are in the two lines between the begin/end statements in the always statement.

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at assignment2_sevenseg.v(14)
>   near text: "(";  expecting ";". Check for and fix any syntax errors
>   that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.

Im also getting that exact error for line 15.

Here is the digitaltimer module too just for reference.

```
module digitaltimer(num , segments); 

input [3:0] num ; 
output [6:0] segments ; 
reg [6:0 ] segments ; 
always@(num)

begin 

case (num)

0: segments <= ~7'b0111111;
1: segments <= ~7'b0000110;
2: segments <= ~7'b1011011;
3: segments <= ~7'b1001111;
4: segments <= ~7'b1100110;
5: segments <= ~7'b1101101;
6: segments <= ~7'b1111101;
7: segments <= ~7'b0000111;
8: segments <= ~7'b1111111;
9: segments <= ~7'b1101111;
default: segments <= ~7'bx ;

endcase
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating modules in an always block. As you've done with your `assignment2_sec` modules, you should instantiate modules "stand-alone", ie, not in any procedural block (such as `always`, `initial`, etc). Remove the `always @(currentTime) begin` and `end` and it should be fine (Im pretty sure the divide and modulo are fine as they are; but Im used to using at least SV-2005, not V2K as you are).

Also note in your `digitaltimer` module, first, use `always @(*)` instead of `always @(num)`, using explicit sensitivity lists as you have done is an easy way to get into trouble. Secondly, using blocking assignment (`=`, not `<=`) in that block as it represents combinational logic. Only using NBA (`<=`) in sequential blocks (things like `always @(posedge clk)`). Finally, `~7'bx === 7'bx` so you dont need to NOT it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is legal:

```
digitaltimer timer(currentTime/10, seg1_output);  //left segment (line 14)
```

You're trying to perform a mathematical operation while instantiating a module. You should perform the division and modulus operations separately with their own reg variables, then connect the output of those operations to the `digitaltimer` module.

Comment: It is legal to use an expression for instantiating module ports, but your recommendation to use separate variables is a good one.